# Are the entity_ids supposed to be incremental in the customer_entity table in Magento? What would cause a jump?

Tags: mysql, magento

I noticed there were periodic jumps in customer number assignment via the back end of Magento and wondered what might cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are supposed to be incremental. I guess it depends on how big the jumps are and if customers are being deleted. But there could be other underlying causes that could be related to lockwait issues or an extension that is not saving customers correctly. But sounds more like that data is being deleted.

Comment: They're only jumping by 1. They seem to be random and infrequent.

Comment: This could be one of : 1°) a customer is deleted and it creates a gap. 2°) an extension reserves an id but do not finalise customer saves and the next customer creation will not use the reserved id and make a jump.